# How should a kubernetes service account and token be configured in Terraform to avoid a race condition?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I've inherited some kubernetes/minikube infrastructure and I'm experiencing an issue where there seems to be a race condition with a service account token being created. This is what we have for the terraform code:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account_v1" "foo-service-account" {
  metadata {
    name = "foo-service-account"
    namespace = "foo-${var.cluster_env}"
  }
  automount_service_account_token = true
}
    
resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "foo-service-account-token" {
  metadata {
    name = "foo-service-account-token"
    namespace = "foo-${var.cluster_env}"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/service-account.name" = "foo-service-account"
   }
 }
  type = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
  wait_for_service_account_token = true
}
```

Roughly 50% of the time, the Makefile commands we run to bring up the apps locally result in an error:

> ╷
> │ Error: secrets "foo-service-account-token" not found
> │
> │   with kubernetes_secret_v1.foo-service-account-token,
> │   on foo.tf line 36, in resource "kubernetes_secret_v1"
> "foo-service-account-token":
> │   36: resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "foo-service-account-token" {
> │
> ╵

We've tried changing the values of `automount_service_account_token` and `wait_for_service_account_token` as well as removing one, the other, or both, and nothing has consistently fixed the issue. Is there something else we should be doing to alleviate the problem?

Comment: Is there any other part of the code where you create e.g, the namespace or where you could create an implicit dependency between resources?

Comment: @MarkoE we specify the namespace resource in the terraform file as well, is that what you mean? Assume in this case that `var.cluster_env = "dev"`


    resource "kubernetes_namespace" "foo" {
      metadata {
        annotations = {
          name = "foo-${var.cluster_env}"
        }
    
        labels = {
          name = "foo-${var.cluster_env}"
        }
    
        name = "foo-${var.cluster_env}"
      }
    }

Comment: Ok, so in that case you can use an implicit reference then to the namespace instead. Something like: `namespace = kubernetes_namespace.foo.metadata.0.name`. If that does not work, then you can try `namespace = kubernetes_namespace.foo.metadata[0].name`.

Comment: @MarkoE can you clarify what you mean by that? I see that we specify the namespaces in the metadata key in each of the resources -- are you recommending specifying it somewhere else?

Comment: No, I'm just saying if you have the namespace resource elsewhere, you just use the implicit reference then instead of `depends_on`, since it can act weird at times.

Comment: @MarkoE is that not what I'm already doing?

Comment: Not really, see my answer.

Comment: @MarkoE someone on another forum suggested using the service account name to create the implicit reference instead of the namespace and that seems to be working. I think maybe you had the right idea but were misreading the error message I received?

Comment: I did have that in my answer: `"kubernetes.io/service-account.name" = kubernetes_service_account_v1.foo-service-account.metadata[0].name`. I was just trying to show the entire code block with implicit dependencies, including namespace. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [depends_on](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) argument?

With it your resources will looks like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account_v1" "foo-service-account" {
  metadata {
    name = "foo-service-account"
    namespace = "foo-${var.cluster_env}"
  }
  automount_service_account_token = true
}

resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "foo-service-account-token" {
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_service_account_v1.foo-service-account
  ]

  metadata {
    name = "foo-service-account-token"
    namespace = "foo-${var.cluster_env}"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/service-account.name" = "foo-service-account"
    }
  }
  type = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
  wait_for_service_account_token = true
}
```

That should prevent race condition since `secret` will always wait for `service account`.

Comment: That seems to be working so far, but since the issue is intermittent I'm going to wait and monitor for a few days before confirming this answer. Thanks!